# Undefined references to any libc symbol despite direct link with archive

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, arm, libc

I am working with the ARM-gcc cross compiler and am having issues linking to any implementation within `libc`.

```
Compiling prog.c, writing to prog.o...
~/.programs/arm-gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -fno-common -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -O0 -g -DF_CPU=72000000 -I~/.programs/arm-gcc/arm-none-eabi/include -I../include -I. -I../src/include -c prog.c -o prog.o > prog.lst

Compiling ../common/sysinit.c, writing to sysinit.o...
~/.programs/arm-gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -fno-common -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -O0 -g -DF_CPU=72000000 -I~/.programs/arm-gcc/arm-none-eabi/include -I../include -I. -I../src/include -c ../common/sysinit.c -o sysinit.o > sysinit.lst

Assembling ../common/crt0.s, writing to crt0.o...
~/.programs/arm-gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=cortex-m4 -o crt0.o ../common/crt0.s  > crt0.lst

Compiling uart.c, writing to uart.o...
~/.programs/arm-gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -fno-common -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -O0 -g -DF_CPU=72000000 -I~/.programs/arm-gcc/arm-none-eabi/include -I../include -I. -I../src/include -c uart.c -o uart.o > uart.lst

~/.programs/arm-gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld prog.o sysinit.o crt0.o uart.o -Map=prog.map -T../common/Teensy31_flash.ld -L~/.programs/arm-gcc/arm-none-eabi/lib  -o prog.elf
prog.o: In function `print_char':
/home/user/workspace/prog/src/prog.c:47: undefined reference to `sprintf'
/home/user/workspace/prog/src/prog.c:48: undefined reference to `printf'
/home/user/workspace/prog/src/prog.c:49: undefined reference to `strlen'
prog.o: In function `main':
/home/user/workspace/prog/src/prog.c:72: undefined reference to `memset'
make: *** [makefile:133: prog.elf] Error 1
```

I threw in a few calls to stdlib to make the point. I have tried to explicitly link against libc using `-lc` but am met with:

```
/home/prog/.programs/arm-gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lc
```

The archive directory *is* passed to the linker via:

```
L~/.programs/arm-gcc/arm-none-eabi/lib
```

I have checked the contents of this directory and verified the archive to be present:

```
$ ls ~/.programs/arm-gcc/arm-none-eabi/lib
aprofile-validation.specs  libc_s.a            linux.specs
aprofile-ve.specs          libg.a              nano.specs
armv6-m                    libgloss-linux.a    nosys.specs
armv7-ar                   libg_s.a            pid.specs
armv7e-m                   libm.a              rdimon-crt0.o
armv7-m                    libnosys.a          rdimon.specs
cpu-init                   librdimon.a         rdpmon-crt0.o
crt0.o                     librdimon_s.a       rdpmon.specs
fpu                        librdpmon.a         redboot-crt0.o
iq80310.specs              libstdc++.a         redboot.ld
ldscripts                  libstdc++.a-gdb.py  redboot.specs
libarm_cortexM0l_math.a    libstdc++_s.a       redboot-syscalls.o
libarm_cortexM4lf_math.a   libsupc++.a         thumb
libarm_cortexM4l_math.a    libsupc++_s.a
libc.a                     linux-crt0.o
```

And, finally, the libc *does* export `sprintf` (and others)

```
$ nm libc.a | grep "sprintf"
...
lib_a-sprintf.o:
00000000 T sprintf
00000000 T _sprintf_r
         U sprintf
         U _sprintf_r
...
```

---

Info on the ARM-GCC build I am using:

```
$ ./arm-none-eabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=./arm-none-eabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/user/.programs/arm-gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/src/gcc/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/install-native --libexecdir=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/install-native/lib --infodir=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info --mandir=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/man --htmldir=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/html --pdfdir=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/pdf --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-newlib --with-headers=yes --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-sysroot=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/install-native/arm-none-eabi --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --with-gmp=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-mpfr=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-mpc=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-isl=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-cloog=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-libelf=/home/build/work/GCC-5-0-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors' --with-multilib-list=armv6-m,armv7-m,armv7e-m,armv7-r,armv8-m.base,armv8-m.main
Thread model: single
gcc version 5.4.1 20160609 (release) [ARM/embedded-5-branch revision 237715] (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `~` in `-L~/.programs/arm-gcc/arm-none-eabi/lib` doesn't get expanded. It is the [shell that expands `~` into `/home/user`, but only when it is at the beginning of a word](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01).

Actually, it isn't necessary to add this `-L` option, because this is already in gcc's default search path. However, you link directly with `ld` instead of with `gcc`. That is not a good idea. It is better to link with `gcc` and allow it to add the default search paths and other required libraries, like `libc` and `libgcc`. Since you supply your own crt0, add `-nostartfiles` to the arguments. So link with:

```
~/.programs/arm-gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc prog.o sysinit.o crt0.o uart.o \
    -Wl,-Map=prog.map -Wl,-T../common/Teensy31_flash.ld -nostartfiles -o prog.elf
```